# Deleting docker files after uninstall

Tags: docker, delete-file

I deleted docker from my Mac. I'm not using boot2docker. Now I want to remove the various files that have been left behind, especially the images to reclaim the space. I intend to reinstall docker and start from scratch. Can I just remove the com.docker.docker directory and all it's sub directories without any harm to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the app isn't enough, you need to run the uninstall steps from the app.

You can also run the following command from a terminal:

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker --uninstall
```